# Why is there discoloration around the base of my faucet?

Tags: kitchens, leak, faucet, sink

Brand new apartment (and faucet) but I suspect a small leak.

Why is the base of the faucet turning the counter orange?

[image]

Comment: If you are referring to the thread thin orangish mark at the base, that is where water collects and does not get entirely wiped up.  Check under the sink for water to indicate a leak.

Comment: Does water ever drip down the faucet from use? Do you ever wipe that area to clean it? Do you have any actual evidence of a leak? Why wouldn't this be a question for your superintendent?

Comment: @ isherwood, The OP didn't indicate that the apartment was rented. There could be no superintendent.  Therefore your comment of questioning the superintendent is useless.

Comment: The base of the faucet is turning orange is probably due to bacteria (Serratia marcescens or Aureobasidium pullulans) from the water drips/splashes alluded to above.  Wet the area and scrub with a nice stiff-bristled brush.